# Could one person move a floating aircraft carrier?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, estimation, drag

Could one reasonably strong person move a floating aircraft carrier?

(EDIT: World's Strongest Man? [1])

Assume perfectly calm water; no ocean waves at all.

Say, by pulling it with an attached rope, or pushing on it.

1. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_Strongest_Man

Comment: I am dubious a single human could pull a rope mooring such a huge vessel with enough force to take the slack off, which would be a minimum requirement to tow the ship.

Comment: As no energy can be lost, even the worlds weakest person capable of applying any force to the ship would have an effect on its motion, although quite miniscule.

Comment: The single human can move the ship. The question is: how fast can a single person make it go?

Answer (score 3):

In principle Newton's Second Law applies:

$$F_{net}=ma$$

If the net force $F_{net}$ acts on a body of mass $m$, that body will experience a uniform acceleration $a$.

Since as in our case:

$$m \gg F_{net}$$

the acceleration will be very small, imperceptible maybe. But allowing enough time ($\Delta t$) movement may become visible, as the velocity is given by:

$$v=a\Delta t$$

However, this does not take into account drag resistance.

> Assume perfectly calm water; no ocean waves at all.

Even ignoring resistances causes by wind and waves, the viscous drag force $F_D$ experienced by the ship's hull cannot be ignored. Because the ship's velocity would be very small (at least at first), $F_D$ would be proportional to velocity:

$$F_D \propto v$$

$F_D$ further reduces the net force acting on the ship:

$$F-F_D=ma$$

where $F$ is the pulling forced exerted by the man.

Answer (score 3):

The work lost by fluid drag effects scales (approximately) with the square of the velocity. This means that for slow speeds, the losses fall more rapidly toward zero than the velocity does. This in turn means that as long as you are OK with slow travel, even a very small force can move a very large mass in a boat or barge. So, on the Erie Canal, a single mule could set in motion and move a huge barge weighing many tons for many miles- at the speed of a walk.

In principle, this means that a single person could set an aircraft carrier into motion as long as its velocity through the water was very close to zero. Whether or not that velocity could be detected is a different matter!

Answer (score -1):

F=ma Force = mass * acceleration even though Aircraft carriers have a far greater mass than humans we can counteract that by adding acceleration. In turn we can unbalance the fores applied on the carrier and it will move with a force that is equivalent to the difference of newtons being applied and and the neutral balance of the twelve physical forces. Assuming all the forces are neutral a slight unbalance could literally set in motion the boat of the carrier and the same principle is the same for all objects with a neutral force applied to them. Take space for example even a very large object like an asteroid can be moved with even a slight imbalance of the forces applied on it.